# query para obter percentagem

Tags: postgresql

Estou a fazer uma *query* para obter percentagem por zona mas não me esta a funcionar lá muito bem

```
    select nuts3_res_1amc.id as id ,nuts3_res_1amc.localidade as source, nuts3_trab.localidade as target ,nuts3_trab.id as id2,
((COUNT(*) * 100)/ 
(select count(*) FROM dados
    INNER JOIN nuts3_res_1amc ON (dados.nuts3_resid_1amc = nuts3_res_1amc.id)
    INNER JOIN nuts3_trab ON (dados.nuts3_trab = nuts3_trab.id)
    INNER JOIN sexo ON (dados.sexo = sexo.id) 
    INNER JOIN meiovida on (dados.meiovida=meiovida.id)
    where  dados.censo='2001' and sexo.sexo='Feminino' and nuts3_res_1amc.localidade!= nuts3_trab.localidade and  nuts3_res_1amc.localidade!='Ainda não tinha nascido' and nuts3_trab.localidade!='Não se aplica'
    group by nuts3_res_1amc.id,nuts3_res_1amc.localidade))as t
    FROM dados
    INNER JOIN nuts3_res_1amc ON (dados.nuts3_resid_1amc = nuts3_res_1amc.id)
    INNER JOIN nuts3_trab ON (dados.nuts3_trab = nuts3_trab.id)
    INNER JOIN sexo ON (dados.sexo = sexo.id) 
    INNER JOIN meiovida on (dados.meiovida=meiovida.id)
    where  dados.censo='2001' and sexo.sexo='Feminino'  and nuts3_res_1amc.localidade!= nuts3_trab.localidade and  nuts3_res_1amc.localidade!='Ainda não tinha nascido' and nuts3_trab.localidade!='Não se aplica'
    group by nuts3_res_1amc.id, nuts3_res_1amc.localidade,nuts3_trab.localidade ,nuts3_trab.id 
    order by id ,id2
```

Se colocar desta forma apenas para o minho funciona bem

```
select nuts3_res_1amc.id as id ,nuts3_res_1amc.localidade as source, nuts3_trab.localidade as target ,nuts3_trab.id as id2,
((COUNT(*) * 100)/ 
(select count(*) FROM dados
    INNER JOIN nuts3_res_1amc ON (dados.nuts3_resid_1amc = nuts3_res_1amc.id)
    INNER JOIN nuts3_trab ON (dados.nuts3_trab = nuts3_trab.id)
    INNER JOIN sexo ON (dados.sexo = sexo.id) 
    INNER JOIN meiovida on (dados.meiovida=meiovida.id)
    where  dados.censo='2001' and sexo.sexo='Feminino' and nuts3_res_1amc.localidade!= nuts3_trab.localidade and  nuts3_res_1amc.localidade='Minho-Lima' and  nuts3_res_1amc.localidade!='Ainda não tinha nascido' and nuts3_trab.localidade!='Não se aplica'
    group by nuts3_res_1amc.id,nuts3_res_1amc.localidade))as t
    FROM dados
    INNER JOIN nuts3_res_1amc ON (dados.nuts3_resid_1amc = nuts3_res_1amc.id)
    INNER JOIN nuts3_trab ON (dados.nuts3_trab = nuts3_trab.id)
    INNER JOIN sexo ON (dados.sexo = sexo.id) 
    INNER JOIN meiovida on (dados.meiovida=meiovida.id)
    where  dados.censo='2001' and sexo.sexo='Feminino' and nuts3_res_1amc.localidade='Minho-Lima' and nuts3_res_1amc.localidade!= nuts3_trab.localidade and  nuts3_res_1amc.localidade!='Ainda não tinha nascido' and nuts3_trab.localidade!='Não se aplica'
    group by nuts3_res_1amc.id, nuts3_res_1amc.localidade,nuts3_trab.localidade ,nuts3_trab.id 
    order by id ,id2
```

Devolve-me este **erro:**

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
>   SQL state: 21000

Comment: As duas consultas são iguais e nenhuma das duas produz o erro apontado

Comment: ja vi que sim tive de fazer um select depois do from